# Error: type(Nonetype) has no len() attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I was trying to solve a problem on leetcode but I keep incurring in an error that I don’t understand

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        char = set()
        longest = []
        curr = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in char:
                longest = max(curr, longest, key=len)
                curr = curr[curr.index(s[i])+1:].append(s[i])
            else:
                curr.append(s[i])
                char.add(s[i])
        return max(curr, longest, key=len)
```

This is the code. The error refers to the fact that when i call the function max() one between curr or longest has no attribute len(). Aren’t both lists?

I looked up the solve but it uses a slightly different method.

Comment: When you set `longest = max...` it ceases to be a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment problem *When you set `longest = max...` it ceases to be a list by [@mark-ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) already*. I will purpose different way of solving this

```py
# lengthOfLongestSubstring
# can be optimized to O(n) using sliding window technique
class Solution2(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        if len(s) == 0:
            return 0
        if len(s) == 1:
            return 1
        max_len = 0
        for i in range(len(s)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
                if len(set(s[i:j])) == len(s[i:j]):
                    max_len = max(max_len, len(s[i:j]))
                else:
                    break
        return max_len


class SolutionWithProblem(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        char = set()
        longest = []
        curr = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in char:
                longest = max(curr, longest, key=len) # problem here
                curr = curr[curr.index(s[i])+1:].append(s[i])
            else:
                curr.append(s[i])
                char.add(s[i])
        return max(curr, longest, key=len)

# call the function
s = Solution2()
print(s.lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb"))
print(s.lengthOfLongestSubstring("bbbbb"))
print(s.lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew"))
print(s.lengthOfLongestSubstring(" "))
print(s.lengthOfLongestSubstring("dvdf"))
print(s.lengthOfLongestSubstring("anviaj"))
print(s.lengthOfLongestSubstring("abba"))
```

This might not be the best solution. Update to your solution

```py
class Solution3(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        char = set()
        longest = []
        curr = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in char:
                if len(curr) > len(longest):
                    longest = curr
                curr = []
                char = set()
            char.add(s[i])
            curr.append(s[i])
        if len(curr) > len(longest):
            longest = curr
        return len(longest)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I took your suggestion and I revisited the whole thing.